# How to change this code to start animate on click

Tags: javascript

When I open this web page, the page automatically redirects to another page.

This code is automatically redirect to the links.

How do I change this code as a click code.

Comment: What do you mean by "click code"?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain a bit more..

Basically what you need is this...

```
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

    myFunction()
    {
    window.location.href = this.options.map[middle].link_url;
    }
```

Or if its a link you want :

```
<a href="this.options.map[middle].link_url">Visit Site</a>
```

As long as you define what "this" is..